# Postgres slow when selecting many rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm running Postgres 11.
I have a table with 1.000.000 (1 million) rows and each row has a size of 40 bytes (it contains 5 columns). That is equal to 40MB.

When I execute (directly executed on the DB via DBeaver, DataGrid ect.- not called via Node, Python ect.):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

it takes 40 secs first time (is this not very slow even for the first time).

The CREATE statement of my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table_1 (
    c1 int8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    c2 int8 NOT NULL,
    c3 timestamptz NULL,
    c4 float8 NOT NULL,
    c5 float8 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT my_table_1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX my_table_1_c3_idx ON public.my_table_1 USING btree (c3);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_table_1_c2_idx ON public.my_table_1 USING btree (c2);
```

On 5 random tables: EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select * from [table_1...2,3,4,5]

```
Seq Scan on table_1  (cost=0.00..666.06 rows=34406 width=41) (actual time=0.125..7.698 rows=34406 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared read=322
Planning Time: 15.521 ms
Execution Time: 10.139 ms

Seq Scan on table_2  (cost=0.00..9734.87 rows=503187 width=41) (actual time=0.103..57.698 rows=503187 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared read=4703
Planning Time: 14.265 ms
Execution Time: 74.240 ms

Seq Scan on table_3  (cost=0.00..3486217.40 rows=180205440 width=41) (actual time=0.022..14988.078 rows=180205379 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=7899 read=1676264
Planning Time: 0.413 ms
Execution Time: 20781.303 ms

Seq Scan on table_4  (cost=0.00..140219.73 rows=7248073 width=41) (actual time=13.638..978.125 rows=7247991 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=7394 read=60345
Planning Time: 0.246 ms
Execution Time: 1264.766 ms

Seq Scan on table_5  (cost=0.00..348132.60 rows=17995260 width=41) (actual time=13.648..2138.741 rows=17995174 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=82 read=168098
Planning Time: 0.339 ms
Execution Time: 2730.355 ms
```

When I add a LIMIT 1.000.000 to table_5 (it contains 1.7 million rows)

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..19345.79 rows=1000000 width=41) (actual time=0.007..131.939 rows=1000000 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=9346
  ->  Seq Scan on table_5(cost=0.00..348132.60 rows=17995260 width=41) (actual time=0.006..68.635 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=9346
Planning Time: 0.048 ms
Execution Time: 164.133 ms
```

When I add a WHERE clause between 2 dates (I'm monitored the query below with DataDog software and the results are here (max.~ 31K rows/sec when fetching): https://www.screencast.com/t/yV0k4ShrUwSd):

```
Seq Scan on table_5 (cost=0.00..438108.90 rows=17862027 width=41) (actual time=0.026..2070.047 rows=17866766 loops=1)
  Filter: (('2018-01-01 00:00:00+04'::timestamp with time zone < matchdate) AND (matchdate < '2020-01-01 00:00:00+04'::timestamp with time zone))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 128408
  Buffers: shared hit=168180
Planning Time: 14.820 ms
Execution Time: 2673.171 ms
```

All tables has an unique index on the c3 column.

The size of the database is like 500GB in total.
The server has 16 cores and 112GB M2 memory.

I have tried to optimize Postgres system variables - Like: WorkMem(1GB), shared_buffer(50GB), effective_cache_size (20GB) - But it doesn't seems to change anything (I know the settings has been applied - because I can see a big difference in the amount of idle memory the server has allocated).

I know the database is too big for all data to be in memory. But is there anything I can do to boost the performance / speed of my query?

Comment: Tip: It'd make more sense if you did `CreatedDate BETWEEN ... AND ...` instead of expressing it this way.

Comment: A) It really sounds like you need indexes on that column. B) Use [ISO 8601 date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), as in `YYYY-MM-DD`. These can be indexed. The dates you have here **cannot be sorted and make absolutely no sense to Postgres**. The way you have it here November comes before February, but after January, or maybe January 11th comes before January 2nd if this is DD-MM-YYYY which is far from clear.

Comment: M2 memory? Do you mean [m.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2)?

Comment: Can you share the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: @tadman PostgreSQL has no problem understanding what '01-01-2019' means as a date, and will  use an index based on that understanding.  It consults DateStyle to decide between MDY and DMY.

Comment: @jjanes Didn't know that, but still, ISO-8601 or bust!

Comment: 1) The memory is Samsung m.2 PRO 1TB X 3. 2) Dates have been updated so it reflect my exact SQL syntax 3) Create statement has been added 4) The motherboard in the server "only" allows 128GB memory.

Comment: How do I know - if my Postgres server has the optimal settings? 40 bytes x 100.000 rows = 4MB. How can 4MB take 21 secs to fetch even the first time (when it is not cached)?

Comment: I have run a Vacuum + Analyse on all tables - but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Your create statements do not show a column CreatedDate, nor an index on it.  Have you renamed it to "c3"?

Comment: jjanes: Exactly - I have anonymized the column names ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `CreatedDate` is indexed.

Make sure `CreatedDate` is using the [`date` column type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-datetime.html). This will be more efficient on storage (just 4 bytes), performance, and you can use all the built in [date formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-formatting.html) and [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html).

Avoid `select *` and only select the columns you need.

Use [`YYYY-MM-DD` ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). This has nothing to do with performance, but it will avoid a lot of ambiguity.

---

The real problem is likely that you have thousands of tables with which you regularly make unions of hundreds of tables. This indicates a need to redesign your schema to simplify your queries and get better performance.

Unions and date change checks suggest a lot of redundancy. Perhaps you've partitioned your tables by date. Postgres has its own built in [table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) which might help.

Without more detail that's all I can say. Perhaps ask another question about your schema.

Comment: 1) CreatedDate is already indexed - please check the updated post. 2) The column type of CreatedDate is timestamptz - is this not okay/optimal? 3) I need all the columns in the small table.

Comment: @PabloDK `timestamptz` is fine. Just don't store dates and times as strings. For me to help more, you'll have to describe why you're unioning 100 tables.

Comment: 1) Because I simply need a lot of mixed sub-periods from all the given tables. 2) But please tell me why 1.000.000 rows takes 40 secs to fetch (when each row is only 41 byte)?

Comment: @PabloDK If you're referring to `select * from table` taking 40 seconds the first time, but being very fast after, its because your caches are cold or perhaps it's GUI tool processing and rendering 1 million rows. Try it in `psql`. Otherwise, we need to see a sample of those tables being union'd.

Comment: Yes - I'm ref. to the "select * from table" taking 40 secs (it always takes long time to execute) :-) Okay - I will try run test with psql as well... Otherwise there is nothing to do?

Comment: @PabloDK There is something to be done: don't fetch 180 million rows and warm your caches. `explain (analyze, buffers) select * from table` includes the cost of fetching all that data. And you're doing it cold, that's what `Buffers: shared hit=[low number]` is, it all has to be read off even a very fast disk. Your query with `limit 1.000.000` was faster because the cache was hot: `Buffers: shared hit=9346`. You're unlikely to fix your performance problem by optimizing `select *`. Again, it's likely your schema and queries which need to be improved.

Comment: I don't run these statement without a WHERE clause (which is between two dates). Its purpose what only to show you the performance/time consumption :-)
I just still wonder how DB reads can be so slow vs. reading the same amount of data directly from disk (even data has to be sorted in the DB first). What else than using an index and running a cluster on all tables to improve speed? Btw - I'm monitored the query with DataDog software and the results are: Max.~ 31K rows/sec when fetching https://www.screencast.com/t/yV0k4ShrUwSd Is that not to be considered as slow?

Comment: @PabloDK Without context like your configuration, exactly what queries you're running, and what else is running at the same time (hopefully nothing) we cannot help you tune your database. We can't interpret a screenshot without context; I can guess, again, that you're blowing out your caches by selecting so many rows. I can only reiterate that your schema and queries are more important than brute performance, and all indications are that the problem is your schema and queries. We've had SQL databases for decades running on far slower hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, all we can do is speculate.

But we can do some pretty good speculation.

Cluster the tables on the index on CreatedDate.  This will allow the data to be accessed more sequentially, allowing more read-ahead (but this might not help much for some kinds of storage).  If the tables have high write load, they may not stay clustered and so you would have recluster them occasionally.  If they are static, this could be a one-time event.

Get more RAM.  If you want to perform as if all the data was in memory, then get all the data into memory.

Get faster storage, like top-notch SSD.  It isn't as fast as RAM, but much faster than HDD.

Comment: 1) What exactly are you asking in regards to: EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)? What SQL should I execute you give you the info you are looking for? 2) The memory is Samsung m.2 PRO 1TB X 3 / The fastest / best I know of... 3) The motherboard in the server "only" allows 128GB memory

Comment: I have run a Vacuum + Analyse on all tables - but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @PabloDK [PostgreSQL EXPLAIN Explained](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-explain/). `Explain` is your basic tool to find out why a query is slow. And you can try `cluster <table> using CreatedDate` which will reorder the table to be more efficient when fetching `CreatedDate` ranges as you are.

Comment: Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..20728.58 rows=1071458 width=41)
Seq Scan on table2  (cost=0.00..328809.16 rows=16996416 width=41)
Seq Scan on table3  (cost=0.00..78231.31 rows=4043831 width=41)

Comment: @PabloDK Those are full table scans. It's not using an index. But without the associated query and schema we can't help.

Comment: @PabloDK  Run the query `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) <your query here>`

Comment: @jjanes I have just updated the post with 5 random runs of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) :-)